# In Ruby on Rails, how to set Base64 encoded string as a pdf attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Base64 encoded PDF data and want to set it as an attachment to a mail using ActionMailer.

I have tried like the following (Assume Base64 encoded pdf data is in `base64_encoded_string`):

```
attachments['attachment.pdf'] = {
  mime_type: 'application/pdf',
  encoding: 'base64',
  content: base64_encoded_string
}
```

But when I open the attached pdf file on the recieved Email, the file is broken.

Now I decode a Base64 string in advance to leave ActionMailer to encode Base64, and it works without any problem.

```
attachments[File.basename('attachment.pdf')] = Base64.decode64(base64_encoded_string)
```

How can you directly set a Base64 encoded string as a pdf attachemnt?

Comment: same issue with a gif, have you found an answer to this issue by any chance ? (I mean even as Base64 encoded content, it is broken in email)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that I found the solution. In case you provide base64 string as a content, make sure to specify the encoding. Otherwise Rails will encode the already encoded string for the second time.

```
attachments['base64_file.pdf'] = {
  mime_type: 'application/pdf',
  encoding: 'base64',
  content: base64_string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Rails [document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html):

> Mail will automatically Base64 encode an attachment. If you want
>   something different, encode your content and pass in the encoded
>   content and encoding in a Hash to the attachments method.

So you just set the content as base64 string without specifying encoding. It will works, this is what I did in my project:

```
attachments['attachment.pdf'] = {
  mime_type: 'application/pdf',
  content: base64_encoded_string
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried as you wrote but I still can't open the attached pdf file. Maybe I have to investigate the problem by something like check binary itself.

Answer (score -3):

This link should help.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base/attachments

```
attachments['attachment.pdf'] = { mime_type: 'application/pdf', 
                                  content:  File.read('/path/to/filename.pdf')}
```